# How to add a record to a table by filling a form and clicking a save button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a button to open the form to be filled. The form to be filled is set to data entry= yes in order to open blank fields anytime  i open it. 
Anytime I open the form and type in any of the fields, it automaically saves in the table. I dont want this because it will create so many blank entries.

So I want the filled data to be recorded if and only if a save button is clicked.

I dont know how to do this yet

Comment: That's how a bound form in Access works. Press _Esc_ multiple times if you regret the filled in values.

Comment: So there is no way to add reocrd to a table with a better control. ?

Comment: You could work with an unbound form and then when pressing your 'save' button, append a new record via VBA by reading the controls and storing them in the regarding table.

Comment: Use code in form BeforeUpdate event to validate data with option to cancel record. Have a public variable in the module that if not set to true by button click, the BeforeUpdate event will read it as false and then cancel the update. Why would there be blank entries? What do you mean by 'blank'?

Comment: What I meant by the blank entries is that with a bound form, soeone could carelessly enter a value in one of the field with no intetion to add any record, this automatically, creates a new record with blank values in all other fields

Comment: You have to either use an unbound form as has been suggested or trap any possible way the user will close/exit the form other than by the "Save" button and delete the new record. I strongly recommend the former especially since it sounds that you are not very experienced with Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a form that is not bound to any query or table. All of the text boxes you put in the form will be blank every time the form is opened. Add a save button with code like this in the On Click event:

```
Sub cmdSave_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Contacts (ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, SponsorID )" _
& " VALUES ('" & Me.txtContactName & "','" & Me.txtContactEmail & "', '" & Me.txtContactPhone & "' , '" & Me.txtSpnID & "')"
```

You can then clear the text boxes for a new entry with something like this:

```
Me.txtContactName = Null
Me.txtContactEmail = Null
Me.txtContactPhone = Null
Me.txtContactID = 0
```